# File header validation

Tags: c#, validation, io

Is there a simpler/cleaner/faster way to do this? I want to make sure the data I need is in the file before I map to my object.

```
var file = File.ReadLines(path).Take(3);
foreach (var line in file)
{
   Validate(line);
   Console.WriteLine(line);
}

public static string Validate(string data)
{
    var first = data.Substring(0, 10);
    var middle = data.Substring(11, 10);
    var last = data.Substring(22, 15);
    var state = data.Substring(38, 2);
    var zip = data.Substring(41, 5);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(first)
            && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(middle)
            && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(last)
            && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(state)
            && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(zip))
    {
        return data;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
}
```

I want this process to be a fast check for nulls before I write the results to the database.  I might also have up to 20 strings to check and I don't like the repetitiveness.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with the way you did it, is it too slow for the number of files you're processing? I don't see a problem with your code.

Comment: _"Is there a simpler/cleaner/faster way to do this?"_ - looks like Code Review is the better site for this. You could trivially do this using a `List<Tuple<int, int>>` though, where you define the ranges to check, and looping over those tuples extracting the substrings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com